# index value vs. flight (data range A row & E row )

Tags: pandas

I want to know the scatter plot of the sum of the flight fields per minute. My information is as follows
http://python2018.byethost10.com/flights.csv

My grammar is as follows

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
matplotlib.rcParams['font.sans-serif'] = ['Noto Serif CJK TC']
matplotlib.rcParams['font.family']='sans-serif'
Df=pd.read_csv('flights.csv')
Df["time_hour"] = pd.to_datetime(df['time_hour'])
grp = df.groupby(by=[df.time_hour.map(lambda x : (x.hour, x.minute))])
a=grp.sum()
plt.scatter(a.index, a['flight'], c='b', marker='o')
plt.xlabel('index value', fontsize=16)
plt.ylabel('flight', fontsize=16)
plt.title('scatter plot - index value vs. flight (data range A row & E row )', fontsize=20)
plt.show()
```

Produced the following error：

> Produced the following error
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "I:/PycharmProjects/1223/raise1/char3.py", line 10, in 
>       Plt.scatter(a.index, a['flight'], c='b', marker='o')
>     File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 3470, in scatter
>       Edgecolors=edgecolors, data=data, **kwargs)
>     File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib__init__.py", line 1855, in inner
>       Return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
>     File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes_axes.py", line 4320, in scatter
>       Alpha=alpha
>     File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\collections.py", line 927, in **init**
>       Collection.**init**(self, **kwargs)
>     File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\collections.py", line 159, in **init**
>       Offsets = np.asanyarray(offsets, float)
>     File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py", line 544, in asanyarray
>       Return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order, subok=True)
>   ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

How can I produce the following results? Thank you.
http://python2018.byethost10.com/image.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is in aggregation, in your code it return tuples in index.

Solution is convert `time_dt` column to strings `HH:MM` by [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
a = df.groupby(by=[df.time_hour.dt.strftime('%H:%M')]).sum()
```

All together:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
matplotlib.rcParams['font.sans-serif'] = ['Noto Serif CJK TC']
matplotlib.rcParams['font.family']='sans-serif'

#first column is index and second clumn is parsed to datetimes
df=pd.read_csv('flights.csv', index_col=[0], parse_dates=[1])
a = df.groupby(by=[df.time_hour.dt.strftime('%H:%M')]).sum()
print (a)
             year  sched_dep_time  flight  air_time  distance  hour  minute
time_hour                                                                  
05:00      122793           37856   87445   11282.0     72838   366    1256
05:01      120780           44810   82113   11115.0     71168   435    1310
05:02      122793           52989   99975   11165.0     72068   515    1489
05:03      120780           57653   98323   10366.0     65137   561    1553
05:04      122793           67706  110230   10026.0     63118   661    1606
05:05      122793           75807  126426    9161.0     55371   742    1607
05:06      120780           82010  120753   10804.0     67827   799    2110
05:07      122793           90684  130339    8408.0     52945   890    1684
05:08      120780           93687  114415   10299.0     63271   922    1487
05:09      122793          101571   99526   11525.0     72915  1002    1371
05:10      122793          107252  107961   10383.0     70137  1056    1652
05:11      120780          111351  120261   10949.0     73350  1098    1551
05:12      122793          120575  135930    8661.0     57406  1190    1575
05:13      120780          118272  104763    7784.0     55886  1166    1672
05:14      122793           37289  109300    9838.0     63582   364     889
05:15      122793           42374   67193   11480.0     78183   409    1474
05:16       58377           22321   53424    4271.0     27527   216     721
```

---

```
plt.scatter(a.index, a['flight'], c='b', marker='o')
#rotate labels of x axis
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.xlabel('index value', fontsize=16)
plt.ylabel('flight', fontsize=16)
plt.title('scatter plot - index value vs. flight (data range A row & E row )', fontsize=20)
plt.show()
```

[image: graph]

Another solution is convert datetimes to times:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
matplotlib.rcParams['font.sans-serif'] = 'Noto Serif CJK TC'
matplotlib.rcParams['font.family']='sans-serif'
df=pd.read_csv('flights.csv', index_col=[0], parse_dates=[1])
a = df.groupby(by=[df.time_hour.dt.time]).sum()
print (a)
             year  sched_dep_time  flight  air_time  distance  hour  minute
time_hour                                                                  
05:00:00   122793           37856   87445   11282.0     72838   366    1256
05:01:00   120780           44810   82113   11115.0     71168   435    1310
05:02:00   122793           52989   99975   11165.0     72068   515    1489
05:03:00   120780           57653   98323   10366.0     65137   561    1553
05:04:00   122793           67706  110230   10026.0     63118   661    1606
05:05:00   122793           75807  126426    9161.0     55371   742    1607
05:06:00   120780           82010  120753   10804.0     67827   799    2110
05:07:00   122793           90684  130339    8408.0     52945   890    1684
05:08:00   120780           93687  114415   10299.0     63271   922    1487
05:09:00   122793          101571   99526   11525.0     72915  1002    1371
05:10:00   122793          107252  107961   10383.0     70137  1056    1652
05:11:00   120780          111351  120261   10949.0     73350  1098    1551
05:12:00   122793          120575  135930    8661.0     57406  1190    1575
05:13:00   120780          118272  104763    7784.0     55886  1166    1672
05:14:00   122793           37289  109300    9838.0     63582   364     889
05:15:00   122793           42374   67193   11480.0     78183   409    1474
05:16:00    58377           22321   53424    4271.0     27527   216     721

plt.scatter(a.index, a['flight'], c='b', marker='o')
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.xlabel('index value', fontsize=16)
plt.ylabel('flight', fontsize=16)
plt.title('scatter plot - index value vs. flight (data range A row & E row )', fontsize=20)
plt.show()
```

[image: graph2]

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I will think again about how to design and deal with this topic.